# Haskell Recursive IO

Tags: haskell, io

I'm having some trouble trying to incorporate a read and write statement into `evaluateStatementInner` function.

I've tried changing the return types of both functions without success.

I'm trying to convert a type `IO(Env)` into `Env`. I know that this can be done with binding in a function that returns an `IO` action but can I do it in the `evaluateInner` statement?

Cheers

Comment: Don't link to external code, extract only what is needed to understand and answer and put it into your question instead. You'll have much more chances to get help ;)

Comment: I guess you can't do `Pure function calling Impure (IO) function` whereas the reverse is true.

Comment: Not really sure on how to call the read inside the inner function.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to be have them in `evaluateStatementInner`? (i.e. why having them in `evaluateStatement` isn't good enough?)

Comment: I thought about that too, but evaluateStatementInner deals with one or more statements that returns an Env whilst evaluateStatement returns IO(Env).
I could n't get it to compile since when using recursion as the function returns IO(Env) whilst I need Env.

Comment: for example if read is called it will return an IO(Env) which I'm unable to pass to the function since its type is env.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluating `Read` and `Write` by necessity involves performing i/o. So bite the bullet and change the type of `evaluateStatementInner` to `Stmt -> Env -> IO Env` (or, better, incorporate it directly into `evaluateStatement`).

You will then need to modify `evaluateListOfStatements` to be of type `[Stmt] -> Env -> IO Env`.

---

So this now gives you a compile error

```
case stmt of
...
    While boolExp innerStmt ->
        if evaluateBoolExp boolExp env
            then evaluateStatementInner (While boolExp innerStmt) (evaluateStatementInner innerStmt env)
            else env
```

because `evaluateStatementInner innerStmt env` yields an `IO Env`, but `evaluateStatementInner (While boolExp innerStmt)` wants an `Env`.

This is a case for monadic bind (and note the else branch needs updating to have the correct type as well):

```
case stmt of
...
    While boolExp innerStmt ->
        if evaluateBoolExp boolExp env
            then evaluateStatementInner (While boolExp innerStmt) =<< evaluateStatementInner innerStmt env
            else return env
```

You might not be comfortable with the monadic operators, so I'll translate it into do-notation:

```
case stmt of
...
    While boolExp innerStmt ->
        if evaluateBoolExp boolExp env
            then do env' <- evaluateStatementInner innerStmt env
                    evaluateStatementInner (While boolExp innerStmt) env'
            else return env
```

Comment: I tried this but I get a compile error on this line: "then evaluateStatementInner (While boolExp innerStmt) (evaluateStatementInner innerStmt env)" where it's saying expected type Env but actual type is IO(Env). This is what I was referring to in the other comment.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I should maybe had got into Haskell a bit more before starting this project. Once I'm done I read up on monadic operators.

Comment: [The Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) has a good section on monads and explains the monadic operators in context (but do read the earlier sections first).

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Until now I've only read the first few chapters of Real World Haskell.

Comment: @user1424720, you should read more chapters :) (and maybe you might like [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) as a tutorial from a slightly different perspective.)